# DataFrame from Array with Header

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have an array with a header row say:

```
arr = ["age" "height" "weight"; 
       20     175     73; 
       30     160     66]
```

and I want to convert it to a DataFrame, what is the recommended method?
My current method is an answer below, any better recommendations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One Liners:

```
# convert a Matrix{Any} with a header row of col name strings to a DataFrame
# e.g. mat2df(["a" "b" "c"; 1 2 3; 4 5 6])

mat2df(mat) = 
    DataFrame([[mat[2:end,i]...] for i in 1:size(mat,2)], Symbol.(mat[1,:]))

# convert a Matrix and a list of col name strings to a DataFrame
# e.g. matncolnames2df([1 2 3;4 5 6], ["a","b","c"])

matncolnames2df(mat, colnames) = 
    DataFrame([[mat[:,i]...] for i in 1:size(mat,2)], Symbol.(colnames))
```

Re: Iain Dunning's comment below: There was a macro here once but the DataFrame constructor it called got deprecated and the above works well, so now it's gone... (Don't worry, it wasn't that good, I think Iain Dunning was just being nice :)

Comment: Awesome macro, very nice

Comment: Attention that if the Matrix to conver has mixed types, the converted DataFrame has all Any's (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46487261/how-to-convert-a-mixed-type-matrix-to-dataframe-in-julia-recognising-the-column/46488660#46488660)

Comment: Updated answer to fix @Antonello's concern, the DataFrame's columns will now have the the correct type